# Creating multiple files at once

Tags: cmd

How can multiple files be created at once in cmd.

Typing "echo>index.html main.js" just creates the index.html file, with the words "main.js" inside it. 
Unlike "md a b" which creates 2 folders.

Comment: In linux you could do that with touch, but for cmd in windows , you might be able to achieve that by using copy command along with echo.

Comment: The only way I could think of is this: `rem/ 9> a.txt 8> b.txt` (you may continue this until `1>`)...

Comment: aschipfl: That works. Can you explain what it means?